# Chrome menu bar disappeared on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1, GNOME 3.28.2.

Since Gnome Global Menus extension doesn't work properly, I was wondering if there is some other  way to get back Chrome top bar/menu(File, Edit, View...).

It's ridiculous that such a basic thing is so hard to configure.

Comment: Chrome itself doesn't come with separate a menu bar as apparently it's designed to work without one, [everything is supposed to be found within the three dots icon](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TfCIsMvQTXY). The global menu bar with "File, Edit, View, ..." etc. was something extra provided by Unity.

Comment: More of the endless GUI confusion. Some apps use the global File menu (e.g. Sublime). Some use the three dots (e.g. Chrome). Some don't bother with anything (e.g. Terminator). Some have 3 dashes (e.g. Firefox). It's 2020 - but we're still in the Wild West as far as GUI conventions go.